# Firestore Security Rules: hasOnly not working?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to update only some fields in the document so I found `hasOnly` function in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasOnly)
but it's not working, for example, the rule below not working

```
function isValid(data){
   return data.keys().hasOnly(['name','email','password'])
}
```

and when I update in client SDK

```
firestore.document("users/user_doc")
            .update(mapOf(
                "name" to "Jack",
                "email" to "jack@gmail.com",
                "password" to "12345"
            )).addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful){
                    Log.d("app", "success")
                }else{
                    Log.d("app", "failed")
                }
            }
```

but it shows an error that missing permission

and also `hasAll` function always return true!
So does this function exist? Why it is not working?

Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that `request.resource` contains the document as it will appear if the write operation succeeds, so it contains existing fields too, not just the ones that you're updating. Does your **document** have more fields than just `name`, `email`, and `password`?

Comment: yes contain other fields but I don't want to update it. My problem is that I want to only update some fields in the document. I can do it by using writeFields but that's been removed in feature. Can you guide me how to update some fields and what the best way to do it? @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An alternative is:

`allow update: if request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).changedKeys().hasOnly(["name", "email", "password"]);`

[New improvements to Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/06/new-firestore-security-rules-features.html)

Comment: Awesome. This is very useful especially in update operations.

Comment: I have noticed that .diff().changedKeys() will only return existing fields difference. It will not prevent new fields in update object from being added.

Comment: @TatiOverflow are you very sure? [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff) say "Compare two Map objects and return whether the key "a" has been affected; that is, key "a" was added or removed, or its value was updated"

Answer (score 14):

Keep in mind that `request.resource contains` the document as it will appear if the write operation succeeds. It contains existing fields too, not just the ones that you're updating.

If there are more fields, you will need to check whether those are unmodified by the write operation. So you'd check that they have the same value in the `request.resource` and `resource`. I often use a function like this in my rules for that:

```
function isUnmodified(key) {
  return request.resource.data[key] == resource.data[key]
}
```

If your document has one additional field `created`, you'd ensure that is unmodified with:

```
return data.keys().hasOnly(['name','email','password', 'created']) && isUnmodified('created')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It help me understand correctly. but what about if client also send other data along with the ```name, email,password``` does the rule rejected ? if not how to write this kind of rule ?

Comment: Your original rule would already reject write operations that add additional fields. But yes, the rule in my answer would reject such writes too. Additionally the rule in my answer rejects writes that change the value of `created`.

Comment: Thanks Frank! I have read the document over and over. But only reading "It contains existing fields too", I started to understand the values of "request.resource".